# HashMap object can't inherit "computeIfAbsent" method from Map class

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to inherit "computeIfAbsent" method from Map class by using a HashMap object. As I know Map is an interface class and HashMap objects are supposed to inherit from Map class. But i can't inherit the method.

my object is:

```
private  Map<PointF, Map<Character, PointF>> function = new HashMap<>();
```

Ps: I am working on Android Studio and my jdk is :1.8.0_11

Comment: FWIW, this sounds like you don't really understand inheritance. Interfaces aren't classes, `HashMap` *implements* `Map`, and you didn't describe at all what "can't inherit the method" means.

Comment: in the documentation of the "HashMap" class on the Android developer website, it says that "HashMap" objects are supposed to inherit methods from "Map" class

Comment: And what Android SDK level?

Comment: i currently build my project on the API Level 15. the problem is maybe because of that

Answer (score 3):

`computeIfAbsent` was added in Java 8 and can't be used in Android before SDK level 24.

Presuming that you *are* using a Java 8-compatible Android SDK, your `Map` variable will have `computeIfAbsent` on it, and you should be able to call

```
Map<Character, PointF> points = function.computeIfAbsent(fooPoint, supplier);
// "function" is a bad name for a map variable
```

Comment: Actually, it exists in Android, but only as of API Level 24. So, a `minSdkVersion 24` app could use it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Forgot Nougat.